# How to find Hash/Cipher

Tags: encryption, hash

is there any tool or method to figure out what is this hash/cipher function?

i have only a 500 item list of input and output plus i know all of the inputs are numeric, and output is always 2 Byte long hexadecimal representation.

here's some samples:

> `794352:6657
>   983447:efbf
>   479537:0796
>   793670:dee4
>   1063060:623c
>   1063059:bc1b
>   1063058:b8bc
>   1063057:b534
>   1063056:b0cc
>   1063055:181f
>   1063054:9f95
>   1063053:f73c
>   1063052:a365
>   1063051:1738
>   1063050:7489`

i looked around and couldn't find any hash this short, is this a hash folded on itself? (with xor maybe?) or maybe a simple trivial cipher?
is there any tool or method for finding the output of other numbers?
(i want to figure this out; my next option would be training a Neural Network or Regression, so i thought i ask before taking any drastic action )

Edit: The Numbers are directory names, and for accessing them, the Hex parts are required.

Comment: A neural network might work, but I somehow doubt that you can extract a meaningful algorithm out of the weights. Start with a small amount of hidden nodes and increase until you trained it with a perfect configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Wikipedia's page on hashes lists three CRCs and three checksum methods that it *could* be.  It could also be only *half* the output from some more complex hashing mechanism.  Cross your fingers and hope that it's of the former.  Hashes are specifically meant to be difficult (if not impossible) to reverse engineer.

What it's being used for should be a *very strong hint* about whether or not it's more likely to be a checksum/CRC or a hash.

Comment: the Hex part is somewhat a safeguard for accessing the directories, but i don't think their content would have any effect on them (they are not checksum of a file or the directory)